# Does <location path="SomePath"> in web.config case sensitive?

Tags: asp.net

I have we config with the following element:

```
  <location path="MyRoot/ServiceCheck.ashx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Does the path value is case sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the path value is case sensitive?

I suspect that will depend on the server you are hosting your application on. IIS on Windows is not case sensitive. But if you work with Mono and host on Apache on Linux (or maybe even Windows?) filenames are case sensitive.